# How to create multi tenant application in Lumen?

Tags: laravel, multi-tenant, lumen, lumen-5.2

I use Lumen and mongodb and i want to create a multi tenant application with Lumen by separate database , subDomain and alias domain for each tenant
Can you friend give me a solution how can i create a multi tenant application in Lumen?

Notice: [this package](https://github.com/thinksaydo/envtenant) for laravel is nice but not work in lumen

Comment: [Landlord](https://github.com/HipsterJazzbo/Landlord) is single database , owner column based tenancy. [Tenanti](https://github.com/orchestral/tenanti) is multi database. Used both but unsure about Lumen support.

Comment: i installed `tenanti` but i got `Call to undefined method Laravel\Lumen\Application::booted() in /vendor/orchestra/tenanti/src/TenantiServiceProvider.php on line 44`